# Python - Result from two list with a list of operators

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to get the result of two lists depending on the operator in another separate column in Python.

Here is my code

```
up = ["123", "1", "7685", "9987"]
down = ["45", "46", "435", "2"]
op = ["+", "-", "+", "*"]

for u, d, o in zip(up, down, op):
    #print(u, o, d)
    #print(int(u) + int(d))
    print(int(u), o , int(d))
```

I can print out but what I want is to get the results. This is the output I am looking for.

```
168 -45 8120 19,974
```

Comment: Append to a list?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use eval() method to evaluate any string as math expression:

```
up = ["123", "1", "7685", "9987"]
down = ["45", "46", "435", "2"]
op = ["+", "-", "+", "*"]

for u, d, o in zip(up, down, op):
    print(eval(u + o + d))
```

Related doc page is [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4985099)